# Override notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have a custom ArrayAdapter. When data is displayed in ListViews  I always want it sorted, therefore I tried to override notifyDataSetChanged() to sort the adapter first, like this:

```
@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    sort(new Comparator<IceContact>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(IceContact iceContact, IceContact iceContact2) {
            return iceContact.compareTo(iceContact2);
        }
    });
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

The class IceContact is a get-set class that implement Comparable. Unfortunately this is giving me a, ironically, StackOverflowError (logcat below). I then tried to do it the other way around. Override `sort()` and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` directly after, like this:

```
@Override
public void sort(Comparator<? super IceContact> comparator) {
    super.sort(comparator);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

That works just fine! Can anyone explain why? It feels like they are pretty much identical implementations.

---

```
01-21 18:25:50.725: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2490): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at android.view.View.setFocusableInTouchMode(View.java:5584)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.checkFocus(AdapterView.java:717)
    at android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AdapterView.java:812)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AbsListView.java:6044)
    at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
    at android.widget.BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(BaseAdapter.java:50)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(ArrayAdapter.java:286)
    at se.naxiait.curbits.utils.IceContactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(IceContactAdapter.java:70)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.sort(ArrayAdapter.java:278)
    at se.naxiait.curbits.utils.IceContactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(IceContactAdapter.java:71)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.sort(ArrayAdapter.java:278)
    at se.naxiait.curbits.utils.IceContactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(IceContactAdapter.java:71)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.sort(ArrayAdapter.java:278)
    at se.naxiait.curbits.utils.IceContactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(IceContactAdapter.java:71)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.sort(ArrayAdapter.java:278)
    at se.naxiait.curbits.utils.IceContactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(IceContactAdapter.java:71)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.sort(ArrayAdapter.java:278)
    at se.naxiait.curbits.utils.IceContactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(IceContactAdapter.java:71)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.sort(ArrayAdapter.java:278)
    at se.naxiait.curbits.utils.IceContactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(IceContactAdapter.java:71)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.sort(ArrayAdapter.java:278)
    at se.naxiait.curbits.utils.IceContactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(IceContactAdapter.java:71)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.sort(ArrayAdapter.java:278)
    at se.naxiait.curbits.utils.IceContactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(IceContactAdapter.java:71)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.sort(ArrayAdapter.java:278)
    at se.naxiait.curbits.utils.IceContactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(IceContactAdapter.java:71)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.sort(ArrayAdapter.java:278)
    at se.naxiait.curbits.utils.IceContactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(IceContactAdapter.java:71)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.sort(ArrayAdapter.java:278)
    at se.naxiait.curbits.utils.IceContactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(IceContactAdapter.java:71)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.sort(ArrayAdapter.java:278)
    at se.naxiait.curbits.utils.IceContactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(IceContactAdapter.java:71)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.sort(ArrayAdapter.java:278)
    at se.naxiait.curbits.utils.IceContactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(IceContactAdapter.java:71)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.sort(ArrayAdapter.java:278)
    at se.naxiait.curbits.utils.IceContactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(IceContactAdapter.java:71)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.sort(ArrayAdapter.java:278)
    at se.naxiait.curbits.utils.IceContactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(IceContactAdapter.java:71)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.sort(ArrayAdapter.java:278)
    at se.naxiait.curbits.utils.IceContactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(IceContactAdapter.java:71)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.sort(ArrayAdapter.java:278)
    at se.naxiait.curbits.utils.IceContactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(IceContactAdapter.java:71)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.sort(ArrayAdapter.java:278)
    at se.naxiait.curbits.utils.IceContactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(IceContactAdapter.java:71)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.sort(ArrayAdapter.java:278)
    at se.naxiait.curbits.utils.IceContactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(IceContactAdapter.java:71)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.sort(ArrayAdapter.java:278)
    at se.naxiait.curbits.utils.IceContactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(IceContactAdapter.java:71)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.sort(ArrayAdapter.java:278)
    at se.naxiait.curbits.utils.IceContactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(IceContactAdapter.java:71)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.sort(ArrayAdapter.java:278)
    at se.naxiait.curbits.utils.IceContactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(Ic
```

Comment: register a DataSetObserver to make the sort

Comment: @njzk2 Thanks! But I'm gonna go with making a new function called just `sort()` (no parameters), so I don't have to pass the comparator every time I want the data sorted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The class IceContact is a get-set class that implement Comparable.
>   Unfortunately this is giving me a, ironically, StackOverflowError
>   (logcat below).

`sort()` calls be default(in its implementation) `notifyDataSetChanged()` which will then call again `sort()` which in turn will call `notifyDataSetChanged()` which will call `sort()` which will call...

In the `notifyDataSetChanged` sort the data **without** also calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` as `sort()` will automatically do that for you.

The second scenario will work as you'll basically call `notifyDataSetChanged()` two times(`super.sort()`, sort the data->`notifyDataSetChanged()` from `super` call-> `notifyDataSetChanged()` call by you)

Comment: Thanks! This was driving me crazy! I'll accept the answer as soon as I'm allowed (a couple of minutes left).

Comment: @njzk2 By `super` call I was referring to the `super.sort()` which will sort the data + call `notifyDataSetChanged()`(+ the extra `notifyDataSetChanged` after `super.sort()`).

Comment: right. my bad, i read've too fast. notifyDataSetChanged is indeed called twice in the second scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `registerAdapterDataObserver`

```
 adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            super.onChanged();
            //your code;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple way to prevent the exception would be to disable the call to notifyDataSetChanged().

```
@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() 
{
    setNotifyOnChange(false);
    sort(yourComparatorInstance);
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

It will be re-enabled automatically accoding to the docs:

> ...and calling notifyDataSetChanged() resets the flag to true.

Which is what sort() does.